# sess.run(train, {x:x_train,y:y_train}) NameError: name 'train' is not defined

Tags: tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow ..i am trying out the example on the https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/get_started 
i have installed tensorflow on python 3.5.2 on Windows 10 laptop

I am getting the following error 
sess.run(train, {x:x_train,y:y_train}) Name Error: name 'train' is not defined

Comment: You do need to define `train`, e.g. `train = optimizer.minimize(loss)`

Comment: after putting this ..getting the following error : During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Ramana\Python\myFirstTesnor.py", line 38, in <module>
    curr_W,curr_b,curr_loss = tf.Session().run([W,b,loss],{x:x_train,y:y_train})
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\client\session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could post your nice clean short code here so we can help you out. My idea is that you forgot to copy-paste these lines:

```
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01)
train = optimizer.minimize(loss)
```

Good luck!